# Progress linear of autocomplete directive looks wrong inside md-content in Angular Material

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive, angular-material

I am using `autocomplete` directive inside `md-content`:

```
<md-content>
    <md-autocomplete>
         ...
    </md-autocomplete>
</md-content>
```

and the progress linear looks a little above:

[image]

if I take this directive outside `md-content`, it looks ok:

[image]

One solution could be not using `md-content`. However, maybe somebody knows how to fix this with `md-content`?

Answer (score 0):

I faced the same issue and it got resolved after i add this :

```
md-progress-linear{

 display:none
```

}

Hope this helps